# ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Specifically, value '*' for key > 'com.apple.developer.associated-domains'

Tags: ios, app-store, provisioning-profile, application-loader

When i try to upload my app (build with Delphi) to the app store I receive this error:

> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application
>   bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not
>   supported on iOS. Specifically, value '*' for key
>   'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in 'Payload/myapp.app/myapp'
>   is not supported."

What does it mean and how can I solve it?

Answer (score -1):

Solution: Remove the Associated Domains entitlement. As the error message said, your entry is incorrect. (Use need to use www.domain.com or *.domain.com) Check the official docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

[image]

If you do want to use deep linking or similar, add a correct value.